# Adding more variables to result every while loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I started to learn python last week and I have to write a while loop where the user is repeatedly asked to input an even number. Then, as long as he inputs an even number, the program should put out the sum of all of the previously added numbers. As soon as an odd number is added, the loop should stop without putting out the odd-numbered result.
Do you have any tipps?
thank you!

Comment: Have you written any code yet?  If so, edit the question to include your progress so far.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I had something similar like the answer below but wrote the number input line before the while loop.

Comment: @EnjaKuro you should still have posted your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
while True:
    number = int(input("enter number:" ))
    if number % 2 == 0:
        total += number
        print(f"Total: {total}")
    else:
        print(f"Final total: {total}")
        break
```

`total = 0` - First, we want to initialize our total variable so that we can use it within the loop to count up the sum of all entries.

The `while True:` line starts an infinite loop. These can be dangerous, but we're going to break out of it later when a condition is met (in this case, an odd number being entered).

`number = int(input("enter number: "))` asks the user for input, converts that input into and int and stores it in the variable called number.

`if number % 2 == 0:` - This checks whether or not the number is even using the modulo operator. This returns the remainder from the division of the first number into the second. For a number to be even, it must have a remainder of 0 when divided by 2.

`total += number` is shorthand for `total = total + number`. This simply adds the user's input to the total.

`print(f"Total: {total}")` prints out the total using an f-string. See [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers) for more info. Essentially, creating an f-string is as easy as putting an `f` before the literal string creation. This allows you to plug variables directly into strings instead of having to rely on the `.format()` method.

The above print line would be written as `print("Total: {}".format(total))` if not using f-strings.

The else statement catches any number that is *not* even, so therefore must be odd. It prints out the final total and then `break` will make us leave our infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see where I went wrong! But what does the 'f' before total and final total do?

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've updated the answer with an explanation of the code.